# TFS for machine applications

Tags: testing, tfs, center

Hallo experts,

I work at a firm as a SW Tester/Validater

Our company produce autoamtic machines. Recently we are introducing team foundation server for SW development. As a SW tester my tasks include:

1. Validation of the functionalities of the machines at the real machines.
2. Reporting bugs and submitting reports.
3. We don't do any UnitTesting.
4. We don't do any code analysis.

I browser the internet and read some related stuffs. My impression on my future testing job after introducing team foundation server could be:

1. Working only with Testing Center
2. (Perhaps) installing TFS
3. (Perhaps) creating virtual environments thru lab center
4. Writing test cases
5. Carrying out tests manually
6. Reporting bugs after implemention by developer

Questions:

1. Are the virtual enviroments useful for SW tests, which needs communication with PLC?
2. Are the virtual enviroments created on the computer of SW tester or on the server?
3. Could SW tester templates for test cases prepare? If yes, how could such work be carried out?
4. For preparation of test plans which events are usually very important?
5. What's test impact?
6. Have you taken a course in order to learn TFS or thru selftaught?

Thanks a lot for your insight in advance.

Best regards,

John

Comment: There are a lot of questions in your post... you might find that you get better answers if you separate them out.  But also, every one of your questions are very subjective and will depend on the requirements of your project, so I don't think you'll get useful answers.  That said, in response to #6, I'm self taught on TFS - the documentation is pretty thorough and it's mostly quite understandable.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I took the liberty to edit your question and adding new lines after each list title (ie. "Questions:"), this allows Markdown to format the lists properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use TFS, check out Test Manager and Lab Manager. It supposedly integrates perfectly with TFS and you might find it, at least, interesting to know about.